# Problems juggling system python and python 27 on Mac Snow Leopard

Tags: python, macos, psycopg2

I had a lot of problems getting geoDjango installed on mac os x snow leopard.

After the dust settled, I realized that the system install of python (2.6) was on the recieivng end of psycopg2

Python 2.7 is on the system path. And when I invoke python in the terminal, python 2.7 is the one the is fired up.

But if I do an easy_install, or mac port install of psycopg2, it doesn't get installed to Libraries/framework.python/verisons/2.7/lib or bin  (i am working from memory here). I do however find a copy installed in the system install of python 2.6

**How do I get things like mac port and easy_install to target python 2.7 and ignore the system python?**

Comment: Something you might want to look into is using homebrew, pip, virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper. It will make managing python and environments so much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve this is to use `virtualenv`.  When you create a virtual environment, you have the option (`-p`) of specifying which Python executable you want.  Once you're in the virtualenv, you don't have to worry about it at all, and all your regular commands (including `pip`) will refer to the proper Python executable, site packages, libraries, etc.

E.g. if you want to create a virtualenv for MacPort's Python 2.7, you can do:

`$ virtualenv -p /opt/local/bin/python2.7 myvirtualenv`

Comment: thanks. That did the trick and will definitely be the go to method in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [macports](http://www.macports.org/) then you shouldhave /opt/local/bin on your path before the systems directories and then you can use `port select python python27` to choose the macports pyton 2.7 . port select in this case changes symbolic links in /opt/local/bin to point to the macports installed 2.7, even in this case you do need to call easy_install-2.7 not just easy_install. Also the macports you want I usually install via an explicit python version e.g. py27-psycopg2, py26-psycopg2.. I think py-psycopg2  has recently been changed so it picks up the python selected by  portselect python.

What the issue is that the easy_install you find on the path is probably the Apple one and easy_install includes the location of the python interpreter inside itself. So you need an easy_install to match each interpreter you have.

macports does not provide a eaxy_install but only one for each version so you can have say a macports python2.7 and 3.2.

If you have other pythons e.g. from python.org and then install setuptools or dustribute you will get an easy_install for that python and that will be in /usr/local/bin.

Comment: This should probably work, but I find MacPorts' assumption that it should be first on your path and responsible for managing Python symlinks to be overstepping its boundaries.  The first thing I always do after installing MacPorts is move it to the back of my path and put it in its place.  See my other answer for a simple solution using virtualenv.

Comment: Macports usually has the newer versions of many things so I want it first on the path